# Add entity reference field to content type

Tags: views

I have 2 content type 1.Employee performance 2.Task

Task content type has a field that assign users to the task (Assigned To Users).Each employee has a node in  Employee performance content type and he is the author of the node. How I can add a select list field in Employee performance that display all the tasks that assign to the employee(author) by using entity reference field in view?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the "Views: Reference by entity reference view" Mode.

You then need to have created an Entity reference view display to correspond to this. In this view you need to pass the current node author as an argument / contextual filter and show all the nodes you want to display there.

Select this view in the entity reference field's settings as attached, an that should do it.

[image]